# Simple SQL convert from RAW to hexadecimal string

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using Java and JDBC API 4.2. I am trying to run a simple select from code and I want to convert a RAW value to a hexadecimal string and to make it lowercase. Nothing works. It looks like this:

```
s.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT LCASE(RAWTOHEX(ID)) FROM TABLE_X");
//s is a java.sql.Statement
```

I tried LOWER instead of LCASE. CONVERT instead of RAWTOHEX but without success. Is the only way is to select all to a java variable and then to parse it in a loop?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the type of the ID column?

Comment: I am using oracle jdbc. The type of the ID column is RAW binary. I need to select the IDs in hexadecimal lowercase string format in order to use them as a foreign key in another table, which some idiot has made to have a different type for the same ID.

Comment: Well, the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm) seems reasonably convenient, and the functions would be `RAWTOHEX` and `LOWER`. By the way: this has nothing at all to do with JDBC, it would do the same if you ran it from SQL*Plus or whatever. As an aside, I'd advise you to lower the rant level. It's not acceptable in posts, and it may cause flame wars and flags. Just provide information relating to the question, regardless of your opinion of whoever was in charge of the database.

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned, I am using a JDBC driver made by Oracle, which is different to ORACLE SQL. It is a translator between queries written in Java code and the underlying database, which could be of any kind. So RAWTOHEX works on regular ORACLE but doesn't work on their JDBC, which I have to use. That is what my question was about.

Comment: Can you give a link to the kind of JDBC you are referring to? And regardless, provide the actual DBMS you are working on which was what I asked in my first question and assumed you actually answered?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql ,then mysql has a method called HEX() using which you can convert into hexadecimal equivalent of input.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LCASE(HEX(ID)) FROM TABLE_X
```

In case of Oracle,use

```
 SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(RAWTOHEX(ID)) FROM TABLE_X
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try HEX. The thing is that LCASE also doesn't work. There has to be support for such simple functions, but I guess it is not easy to find. The documentation of Oracle is terrible

Comment: @Alex Please mark the solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved...I have updated the solution some time back...